# How to run a Spring MVC project on Bluemix?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have successfully pushed my Spring MVC application to the cloud using Cloud Foundry. However, I get the following exception when I try to access the URL:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught
>   initialization exception created by servlet

Here is the error get when I access the URL:

```
App/0[ERROR ] Context initialization failed2016-08-27T16:12:30.073+0530
App/0Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.covenant.app.dao.UserRepository com.covenant.app.services.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined2016-08-27T16:12:30.073+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2390)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0[ERROR ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [dispatcher] in application [myapp]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.covenant.app.dao.UserRepository com.covenant.app.services.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:528)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)2016-08-27T16:12:30.074+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 ... 28 more2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:572)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:694)2016-08-27T16:12:30.075+0530
App/0 at [internal classes]
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I am stuck at this point of time. All of my spring MVC configuration is in the Java config. Is there any problem if I have all of it in my Java config when deploying to Bluemix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was calling my local data source for MySQL with DriverManager to get the data source. However, when I changed it to Basic DataSource for Bluemix, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the article and able to deploy and test Spring MVC using bluemix.
Modified MySQL to dashDB (equivalent of IBM DB2). The URL is
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-jdbctemplate-example. Also tested locally with DB2 and IBM Liberty Server and it works.